# how can i concatenate determined number of characters with another string?

Tags: c, string

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a function that can concatenate determined number of characters to another string. It's counting the number of characters correctly but it wont display like the task wants.
Anyone could explain me why?

**An example would be (expected output):**

String 1: Testing

String 2: String

N: 4 (Value is asked for the user)

Result: TestingStri

**My code so far is this:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
void ConcatenateString(char *string, char *string2); 
int main() 
{ 

   char string[100]; 
   char string2[100]; 

   ConcatenateString(string, string2);
   DisplayStrings(string, string2); 

} 
void ConcatenateString(char *string, char *string2)
{
    int N;
    system("cls");
    printf ("First string: ");
    gets(string);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf ("Second string: ");
    gets(string2);
    printf("Number of characters: ");
    scanf ("%d", &N);

    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for(i=0;string2[i];i++)
    {
        count++;
    }

    while (count < N)
    {
        string2[count++] = string2[i];
    }   
    strcat(string,string2); 
}
void DisplayStrings(char *string, char *string2)
{
    printf("\nFirst String:\n");
    printf("%s\n", string);
    printf("\nSecond String:\n");
    printf("%s\n", string2);

}
```

The wrong (actual) output:

```
String 1: Testing
String 2: String
N: 4
Output: TestingString
```

It's not really displaying 4 characters from string 2 (for example) that I ask for.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;string2[i];i++)
{
    count++;
}
```

This code counts the number of bytes in `string2`. I think you want `string` here instead.

---

```
while (count < N)
{
    string2[count++] = string2[i];
}
```

This code copies stuff in `string2` from one place to the other. I think you want to copy from `string2` to `string` instead.

---

```
strcat(string,string2);
```

This code concatenates `string` and `string2`. You definitely don't need this; it will only confuse you when you display the result.

Comment: Terminating '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

**Which book are you reading?**

The pervasive errors you have are common for the populous who *don't read books*. That is to say, from my observations, those who read books don't have these kinds of problems...

- `system("cls");` makes no sense when you learn from a nice book, as it defeats the purpose of the lesson it should teach: use the most appropriate tool for the job, and if you want to *clear the screen* that tool is a *user interface* other than the *console*. Don't clear consoles, and certainly don't use `cls` to do so. Consider anyone who uses Unix (and so no `cls` command exists); at best your code will show an error, and at worst `cls` could be a malicious program.
- Older books are still using `gets`, but that has been deprecated. Consider using `fgets` instead.
- [You should **never** <strike>`fflush(stdin)`</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/1989425). On that note, you should probably `fflush(stdout)` when you're writing data that doesn't end with `'\n'` to `stdout`.
- `int n = scanf(...);` make sure you check `n`... and don't just *guess*; read [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html).

> ```
> int i;
> int count = 0;
> for(i=0;string2[i];i++)
> {
>     count++;
> }
> ```

Since `count` and `i` both increment synchronously and start at `0`, they'll both be equal to `strlen(string2)` here. You should just write `count = strlen(string2);`... on that note, these variables should be `size_t`, rather than `int`.

---

> ```
> while (count < N)
> {
>     string2[count++] = string2[i];
> }
> ```

This is undefined behaviour, at least for values of `N` that are larger than `string2`. It's essentially `memset(string2 + count, '\0', N - count)`; that is to say, all you are doing here is zeroing the bytes at the end of the array. You don't need this code. Get rid of it. Burn it in fire!

---

```
fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin);
fgets(string2, sizeof string2, stdin);
```

> ```
> strcat(string,string2);
> ```

Ahh, why didn't you do that in the first place? Don't forget to remove the newline characters...

Answer (score 1):

As others have told you, never use `gets()` as it is infamous for its security issues.  Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Use `fgets()` like

```
char str[100];
fgets(str, 100, stdin);
```

You may check the value returned by [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to see if all went well. `NULL` is returned on error.

`fgets()` will read in the trailing `\n` as well. You may remove it like

```
size_t l=strlen(str);
if(str[l-1]=='\n')
{
    str[l-1]='\0';
}
```

to replace the `\n` with `\0` denoting end of string.

---

To concatenate `n` characters of a string `str2` to `str1` (assuming that `str1` has enough space. Checks against overflow must be in place when you do this), you could do

```
sprintf(str1, "%s%.*s", str1, n, str2);
```

The value of `n` will stand in for the `*` in the format string. So if `n` is `4`, it will be `%.4s` which means the first `4` characters from the corresponding string.

Before doing this, check if `str1` has enough space with something like

```
if(strlen(str1)+n+1 < 100)// where 100 is the size of the character array str1
{
    sprintf(......);//the sprintf() call
}
```

---

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209/5375464) post to see why `fflush(stdin)` is not considered good.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913446/why-should-the-system-function-be-avoided-in-c-and-c) to see why the use of `system()` is better avoided.

Comment: @snr Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @snr What do you mean?