# Passing struct array to function for input

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm working on a program in C language which collects data for the employees such as names, rates and hours. The thing is I need to use `struct`.

I am trying to pass struct array into the `load()` function where user will put names, hours and rates of the employee but it seems I'm doing it wrong. Can you tell me what is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 3
int i = 0;
struct Employee
{
    char name[20];
    float rate;
    float hours;

}employee;


void load(struct Employee *guys);
void printout();
void edit();
void realedit();
void print();

int main(void)
{   
    int x=0;
    struct Employee guys[size];


    while (x != 5)
    {
        printf("Main Menu\n");
        printf("1. Add Employee\n");
        printf("2. Edit Employee\n");
        printf("3. Print Employee\n");
        Printf("4. Print All Employees\n");
        printf("5. Quit");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);

        switch (x) 
        {
        case 1: load(guys[i]);
            break;


        default: printf("Please enter valid option.\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void load(struct Employee *guys)
{
    puts("\ntype name:\n");
    scanf_s("%s", &guys[i]->name, 20);

    puts("\ntype hourly rate:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &guys[i]->rate);

    puts("\ntype hours worked:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &guys[i]->hours);


    i++;
}
```

Comment: When you are passing guys[i] to load, have load retreive Employee &emp. Then simply store the data using emp.name. Note that it is not good practice to have  ' i ' as a global variable.

Comment: Here `load(guys[i]);` passing structure by value but `load()` parameter expect a pointer to the `struct Employee`.

Comment: Don't forget to check the the `scanf_s()` calls succeed; the one in `main()` should be checked to ensure it returns 1, otherwise there is a problem.

Comment: A *global variable* of `int i = 0;` is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 4):

With the

```
load(guys[i]);
```

in your program, you are passing the `i`th element of the `guys` array to `load()` by value. So what's being used in `load()` is actually a copy changes to which will not affect the original value back in `main()`.

Instead you could pass a pointer pointing to the `i`th element to `load()` like

```
load(&guys[i]);
```

And use the `->` operator to access the variables inside the `struct`.

```
void load(struct Employee *guys)
{
    puts("\ntype name:\n");
    scanf_s("%s", guys->name, 20);

    puts("\ntype hourly rate:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", guys->rate);

    puts("\ntype hours worked:\n");
    scanf_s("%f", guys->hours);
}
```

And no need to use `[i]` for indexing as we take care of elements one by one.

---

In

```
scanf_s("%s", &guys[i]->name, 20);
```

the function expects the base address of the array. So use

```
scanf_s("%s", guys[i]->name, 20);
```

as the name of the array decays into a pointer to the first element of the array.

As for your use of `system()` in

```
system("pause");
```

consider reading 
[Why should the system() function be avoided in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913446/why-should-the-system-function-be-avoided-in-c-and-c).

Also, note that [`puts()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/puts) will automatically print a `\n` at the end. So, if you see fit you can do away with a `\n`.

And you have a small typo. The

```
Printf("4. Print All Employees\n");
```

should've been

```
printf("4. Print All Employees\n");
```

Comment: Alternatively: `load(guys + i);`

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah, true.