# How do I utilize fprintf within an array?

Tags: c

I need some assistance. I'm trying to write my code's output into a file. 
However, I'm encountering an issue whenever I attempt to use fprintf within an array. The code works as it should without the fprintf statements, printing 5 scores per line. When added, it appears to continue increment the array?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void displayScore(int testScores[]);
FILE *fpOut;

int main(void) {

if (!(fpOut = fopen("csis.txt", "w"))) {
    printf("csis.txt could not be opened for input.");
    exit(1);
}

int testScores[] = { 90, 85, 100, 50, 50, 85, 60, 70, 55, 55, 80, 95, 70, 60, 95, 80, 100, 75, 70, 95, 90, 90, 70, 95, 50, 65, 85, 95, 100, 65 };

displayScore(testScores);

fclose(fpOut);
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void displayScore(int testScores[]) {
int i = 0;

/*Prints 5 scores every line*/
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", testScores[i]);
    fprintf(fpOut, "%d, ", testScores[i]);
    printf("%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
    fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
    printf("%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
    fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
    printf("%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
    fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
    printf("%5d, \n", testScores[i += 1]);
    fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, \n", testScores[i += 1]);
}
return;
}
```

Comment: The error message if you fail to open `csis.txt` is quite misleading, as you don't open the file for input at all.

Comment: As for your problem, nothing a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) shouldn't help... Hint: How many times do you increase `i` with `i += 1`? How many times *should* you do it?

Comment: Hint received, face-palm x20,

Still relatively new to this. Wasn't sure if there was some operator I needed to use or special syntax. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, `i += 1` is exactly equivalent to `++i`

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, with

```
printf("%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
```

you are printing one number to `stdout` and the next number to the file. So every alternate number will end up in the file and the other numbers will be printed out to `stdout`.

You could modify this to

```
printf("%5d, ", testScores[i]);
fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i]);
i+=1;
```

ie, increment `i` only after printing to both `stdout` and the file.

Or you could use the postfix increment operator like

```
printf("%5d, ", testScores[i]);
fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i++]);
```

here in `i++`, the value of `i` will be incremented but the initial value of `i` will be used in the expression. Read [What is the difference between prefix and postfix operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031326/5375464) .

And instead of repeating by yourself, you could make the computer do the repeating with something like

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    printf("%5d, ", testScores[i]);
    fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i]);
    if((i+1)%5==0)
    { 
        printf("\n");
        fprintf(fpOut, "\n");
        }

}
```

and print the newline only if `i+1` is divisible by `5`.

---

The use of `system()` is discouraged. See [Why should the system() function be avoided in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913446/5375464) .

Answer (score 0):

> When added, it appears to continue increment the array?

Yes, you increment your array index too often:

```
printf("%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
fprintf(fpOut, "%5d, ", testScores[i += 1]);
```

You increment your counter `i` once for `printf` and once again for `fprintf`.
While you probably want to print the same element in both commands, you access two adjacent elements.

To fix this only increment once.