# Can i use two strings in system()?

Tags: c++

I am trying to do something like this:

```
     {
      cout << "command: ";
      cin >> m;
      cout << "option: ";
      cin >> o;
      system(m+o);
     }
```

so that the user can choose which command to run and an option if wanted

Comment: Did you try it? Did it fail?

Comment: Sure, but you're going to have a bad time security-wise.

Comment: It depends on what `m`and `o` are. But anyway you probably rather want `m + " " + o`.

Comment: it failed even when i added .c_str() to both m and o,because if i added it only to m(which had red error line under it) it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @CyberSlayer: You need parentheses so that you call `.c_str()` on the whole of `(m+" "+o)`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Short of a bad `sudo` rule or sticky bit, this is safe. The program runs a command with the same credentials as itself, which the user could also enter directly into the shell.

Comment: if `m` and `o` are two strings, then `m + o` isnt "two strings", but only one. Please provide a [mcve] and report errors if any in the question

Comment: @MSalters I'm internet-oriented. I was thinking about that kind of stuff.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Agree with [mcve] but the question is reasonable. He does have two strings, and his concatenation appear to fail. So it's reasonable to ask if `system` can take two strings instead so that there's no need to concatenate them. It's even more reasonable because `CreateProcess` on Windows does take command and options as two separate strings.

Comment: @MSalters I didnt want to imply that the quesiton is not reasonable. I think you refer to the difference between a "please fix my code" and "how can I do X" question. I am not trying to suggest that the latter would make a worse question, its just that `m+o` can go wrong in several ways, but not if they are `std::string`s which isnt mentioned explicitly yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [system ()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/) function expects a `char *` parameter, you also are forgetting the space separation. You should do something like this:

```
system(std::string(m + " " + o).c_str())
```

Anyway I strongly recommend you not to use the `system ()` function because it's a big security hole.

For more details about this I suggest you to read the following post:

- [Why should the system() function be avoided in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913446/why-should-the-system-function-be-avoided-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Could you describe the _big security hole_?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass only argument to [`system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) - a null terminated C-style string. However, that string may contain a command to any degree of complexity as long as the host system can handle that command.

Examples:

```
system("ls");
system("ls -alF");
system("ls -alF | some-other-program ");
```

Assuming `m` and `o` are of type `std::string` in your posted code, you probably need to use:

```
std::string command = m + " " + o;
system(command.c_str());
```

Comment: I don't think the last one works reliably, as `ls` has no idea what to do with `|`. It might work if the shell picks up on the `|` but `system` isn't _that_ well defined.

Comment: @MSalters, `system` is agnostic about what the host does with the command. It's only the host that decides whether the command is valid.

Comment: @MSalters `system` is defined to handle the command through a shell, so `|` will be correctly interpreted if the standard command interpreter of the host handles it.

Comment: "you can pass only **one** argument..." ?

Comment: @MSalters `system` invokes "the host environment's command processor". That's a shell. It's going to work.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: True. On POSIX it will work, and I suspect Windows can handle it too. (The ` |` part that is, not the `ls`)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, I didn't follow your drift.